# I can't get accurate value in dictionaries in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

Whenever I try to print the dictionaries in Django I can't get what I need. The views models are given below. Geeks help to solve this beginner question

**Views.py**

```
def home(request):
    roomCate=dict(Room_Type.ROOM_CATEGORIES)
    roomUrl=Room_Type.objects.all()
    print(roomCate)
    print(roomUrl)
    return render(request,'index.html')
```

Whenever I print `roomCate` and `roomUrl`, I got what I need in `roomUrl` but, in `roomCate` I changing while printing the dictionaries of value,
`<QuerySet [<Room_Type: Sig>, <Room_Type: Lux>, <Room_Type: Elt>]>` The value is not changing while print the value

But in `{'Lux': 'Luxury', 'Sig': 'Signature', 'Elt': 'Elite'}` the value is changing.

Here is my **models.py**

```
class Room_Type(models.Model):
    """Django data model Room_Type"""
    ROOM_CATEGORIES={
    ('Elt','Elite'),
    ('Lux','Luxury'),
    ('Sig','Signature')
    }

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="pics")
    roomtype = models.CharField(choices=ROOM_CATEGORIES,max_length=20)
    price = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.roomtype}'
```

I want the method print result same as `roomUrl` but I can't get the value same as `roomUrl`. Please geeks help me solve this

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You want the full forms right.
So you can call
roomCate=dict(Room_Type.ROOM_CATEGORIES).values()

In views.py

Comment: dict_values(['Elite', 'Luxury', 'Signature'])
<QuerySet [<Room_Type: Sig>, <Room_Type: Lux>, <Room_Type: Elt>]>

Comment: I got like this,Please help to create perfect zip() key value pair